# SCNPhysicsWorld Error

Tags: xcode, ios8, scenekit

I've been messing around with swift and trying to get a Physicsworld working.

This is the error I get
"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNPhysicsWorld", referenced from:
      __TFC3sk218GameViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ in GameViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"

I assume it has to do with linking or importing a library that I'm not, but I have added everything that I could find that I thought might fix it (found in other posts on game kit)  Does anyone know what this might be?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you running Xcode 6 beta on OS X 10.9? Physics is a new feature in Scene Kit for 10.10.

Comment: Ahh... Yes. I'm running xcode beta6 on osx 10.9

Comment: I'm running the ios 8 simulator though. I didn't think the os would cause that issue as the software is for ios.

Comment: I've had this error too - physics is otherwise working but you can't seem to access the physicsWorld property? This is accessible if you use objective-c though so seems odd

Comment: Yea, I've been trying to learn some swift is all.

Comment: I see this too – This actually seems like a bug in the Swift-Objective-C bridge / Xcode 6. The documentation is pretty clear that it should be accessible.

Comment: FWIW, I filed rdar://17264213

Answer (score 8):

There is a bug here with the Obj-c / Swift bridge.

While you wait for a solution, you can work around this by creating a temporary bridge for yourself:

Add the following class:

**PhysWorldBridge.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>//

@interface PhysWorldBridge : NSObject

- (void) physicsWorldSpeed:(SCNScene *) scene withSpeed:(float) speed;
- (void) physicsGravity:(SCNScene *) scene withGravity:(SCNVector3) gravity;

@end
```

**PhysWorldBridge.m**

```
#import "PhysWorldBridge.h"

@implementation PhysWorldBridge

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) physicsWorldSpeed:(SCNScene *) scene withSpeed:(float) speed
{
    scene.physicsWorld.speed = speed;
}

- (void) physicsGravity:(SCNScene *) scene withGravity:(SCNVector3) gravity
{
    scene.physicsWorld.gravity = gravity;
}

@end
```

Xcode should prompt you to create a `XXX-Bridging-Header.h` when you add the first objective-c file. Let it create this file.

Add an import for the class to the 'XXX-Bridging-header.h":

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "PhysWorldBridge.h"
```

Now you can use this (hacky) bridge to set the properties from Swift:

```
//scene.physicsWorld.speed = 2.0
// CAN'T USE ABOVE OR LINKER ERROR


let bridge = PhysWorldBridge();
bridge.physicsWorldSpeed(scene, withSpeed: 2.0);
//This call bridges properly

//So would the gravity one:
bridge.physicsGravity(scene, withGravity: SCNVector3Make(0, -90.81, 0));
```

Comment: I think it will be better to use static class for all inconsistencies, in the future when bug will be fixed, just replace static lines with swift code.