# MKMapRectUnion doesn't work correctly in Swift and Xcode 6

Tags: swift, mapkit, xcode6

It seems that MKMapRectUnion doesn't work correctly if invoked by Swift in Xcode 6. Here is the test code:

```
    var lat = 37.33072
    var lon = -122.029674
    var loc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    var point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(loc)
    var flyTo = MKMapRect(origin: point, size: MKMapSize(width: 1,height: 1))
    println("before: \(flyTo.origin.x) \(flyTo.origin.y) \(flyTo.size.width) \(flyTo.size.height)")
    flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, flyTo)
    println("after: \(flyTo.origin.x) \(flyTo.origin.y) \(flyTo.size.width) \(flyTo.size.height)")
```

The println should print the same value in both cases because the rect is unioned with itself. However, the code above prints different values as below:

```
before: 43225808.0396629 104173696.109851 1.0 1.0
after: -3.83373425165789e-307 1.46741238348183e-306 9.00321006028138e-314 5.29980882362664e-315
```

I tried the above code (written in objective-c) and got the same result for before and after.
Anyone here has  encountered the same thing? Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: I get the same before and after in a Playground. File a bug?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the current beta.  You can try the Objective-C/Swift bridge workaround shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128723/scnphysicsworld-error) as a temporary fix.  Essentially, do the MKMapRect and Union calls in Objective-C and call your bridge methods from Swift.

Comment: I actually tried that but no luck. Before and after are still different just like in Swift.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by putting the MKMapRectMake and MKMapRectUnion calls in Objective-C.  The Swift code should only pass double values and get back a final MKMapRect.