# MKMapRectMake in Swift causes linker error when compiling

Tags: swift, mapkit, xcode6

Using MKMapRectMake to create MKMapRect causes compiling error as below:

This is my code:

```
    var lat = 37.33072
    var lon = -122.029674
    var loc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    var point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(loc)

    var flyTo = MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, 0, 0);
```

and this is the error from the compiler:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MKMapPointMake", referenced from:
      _MKMapRectMake in ViewController.o
  "_MKMapSizeMake", referenced from:
      _MKMapRectMake in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My work-around for this is create MKMapRect using the origin and size parameters. Note that I have added MKMapKit to the linked libraries in Build Phases

Is there anyone encounter the same issue and how you fix this?

Comment: Make sure the parameters have the same type that the function accepts. They need to be `Double` values.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the current beta.  You can try the Objective-C/Swift bridge workaround shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128723/scnphysicsworld-error) as a temporary fix.  Essentially, do the MKMapRect calls in Objective-C and call your bridge methods from Swift.

Comment: Thanks. This could be another option to try.

Answer (score 7):

Work around it with a utility function:

```
func myMKMapRect(x: Double, y:Double, w:Double, h:Double) -> MKMapRect {
    return MKMapRect(origin:MKMapPoint(x:x, y:y), size:MKMapSize(width:w, height:h))
}
```

And file a bug report with Apple, of course.

Answer (score 1):

change this 
var flyTo = MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, 0, 0);

to

var flyTo = MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPointMake(x:point.x, y: point.y),size MKMapSizeMake(width:0, height: 0) )

MKMapRect has an origin and size argument, which you are missing

MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPointMake(x:, y: ),size MKMapSizeMake(width: , height: ) )

Answer (score -2):

var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
var boundingMapRect : MKMapRect

these two are the required properties for MKOverlay, add them.